# Got a persistent change font size slider in Jquery but need help to turn into Vanilla js

Tags: javascript, jquery

Now I have this Jquery font rezising slider but need it in vanilla.js. It is working properly but I can not manage turning it into plain Javascript.

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="font-slider">
        <input type="range" min="17" max="28" value="22" step="1" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <h1>Changing Font Size</h2>
            <p>I am just a boring text, existing here solely for the purpose of this demo</p>
            <p>And I am just another one like the one above me, because two is better than having only one</p>
            <a href="#">I am a link, don't click me!</a>
    </div>
    <script>
        var curSize = localStorage.getItem("saveSize");
        if (curSize) {
            var saveSize = curSize;
            $('body').css('font-size', saveSize + 'px');
            var setSize = $('body').css('font-size');
        }
        $('.font-slider input[type="range"]').on("input change", function () {
            var newSize = $(this).val(),
                defaultSize = $("body").css("font-size"),
                minSize = 17,
                maxSize = 28;

            if (newSize <= maxSize && newSize >= minSize) {
                $("body").css("font-size", newSize + "px");

                localStorage.setItem("saveSize", newSize);
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What did you attempt, seems pretty straight forward with addEventListener and some setting of styles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
var curSize = localStorage.getItem("saveSize");
var slider = document.querySelector('.font-slider input[type="range"]')
var body = document.body

if (curSize) {
    var saveSize = curSize;
    body.style.fontSize = saveSize + 'px';
}

slider.addEventListener("input", function (e) {
    var newSize = this.value,
        defaultSize = body.style.getPropertyValue('font-size'),
        minSize = 17,
        maxSize = 28;

    if (newSize <= maxSize && newSize >= minSize) {
        body.style.fontSize = newSize + 'px';

        localStorage.setItem("saveSize", newSize);
    }
});
```

Comment: Mikhail, this code of yours is working as well as the jquery example I had. Thank you very much. You've been a saviour.

Comment: And what about if instead of changing the font size of de body tag I rather prefer to change just some tags or even some css classes? Would it be possible?

Comment: @SIMBIOSIS of course. First you obviously should declare variable contains tag you want change: `var somePTag = document.querySelector('.classofthisp')` and set font size to it like this: `somePTag.style.fontSize = newSize + 'px'`

Comment: Yes, that's correct. But I meant, for example, something like this `"p, h1, .container, blockquote,..."` where I may declare, in a single var, all the classes I would like to include to be affected by the font size slider